# Angular - Add option to select using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that adds **new options** to a select.

For that i'm using:

```
let opt: any = angular.element(
            '<option value="' + opcion.valor + '">' + opcion.texto + '</option>'
          );
          this.element.append(this.$compile(opt)(scope));
```

I don't want to use templates because I don't want a new scope.

The options get added to the list on the view. But when I select some of them, the ng-model of the select doesn't get updated. It gets value *null*.

How can I make angular to refresh with the new option values?

Here is a codepen example:
Choosing Option X doesn't get reflected on model.

The strange thing is that if i link to angular 1.5.9, it works, but starting with angular 1.6.0 it doesn't.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XemqGb?editors=0010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In latest angularJS [Select value (read from DOM) is validated](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/9bcdfcfe17f2655b11350aad5846a9a3cc481cc2/src/ng/directive/select.js#L211)

Better to use select's in standard way,

BTW - If you really need this, remove validation by decorating `selectDirective` as follows

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NapVwN?editors=1010#anon-login

```
myApp.decorator('selectDirective', function($delegate) {
    let originalCtrl = $delegate[0].controller.pop();
    $delegate[0].controller.push(function() {
      originalCtrl.apply(this, arguments);
      this.hasOption = function() { 
        return true; 
      }
    })
    return $delegate;
});
```

Answer (score 8):

> How can i make angular to refresh with the new option values ?

You do not need to do this. Updating `model` and `data binding` is done by `digest` cicle.

`Data binding` means that when you change something in the view, the **scope** model **automatically** updates.

You just need to update your **scope** and `digest` cicle is dealing with the rest of work.

I recommend you to not mix `jquery` with `angularJS`.

You should definitely try to do things the `angular` way when **possible** though.

You should not use **jQuery** on the top of the **AngularJS**, because **AngularJS** `digest` cycle won't run if we do any angular DOM manipulation or scope variable manipulation using `JQuery`.

**However**, you can do this `manually` using `$scope.$apply()` method by passing a `callback` function.

HTML

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue">
  ....
</select>
```

JS

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var selectScope = angular.element($("select")).scope();
    selectScope.$apply(function(){
        selectScope.selectedValue=value;
    });
});
```

Comment: I understand the warning about jquery. That's why i'm using it only in a Directive. I want to add new options to the select but without using a new template for the directive.

Comment: @MartinIrigaray, yes, you could do this by applying manually `$scope.$apply` method.

Comment: @MartinIrigaray, I updated my answer with a possible solution in order to update the scope of the select.

Comment: I put an example on codepen, is not working on angular 1.6.5.

Comment: it is important to note though that the `scope()` function on an element is only meant to be used for debugging/testing purposes and it is not meant to be used in actual code

Answer (score 5):

> I want to add new options to the select but without using a new template for the directive

Use `compile` attribute in directive:

```
myApp.directive('myList', function() {
   return {
        restrict: 'EA', //E = element, A = attribute, C = class, M = comment
         link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
             // ....
        }, //DOM manipulation
         compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
           tElement.append('<option value="10">Option Ten</option>');
        }
      }
  });
```

<kbd>[Updated Demo Codepen](https://codepen.io/Fess-81/pen/LzbyMV?editors=1010)</kbd>

---

**[EDIT 1]**

> Is possible to do this after a change on external model field ? Watch a field and then add the option ?

Not at all. `compile` is called once right after we created the instance. This is a phase when Angularjs compiles the directive

However if you want to create value after some delay based on external flow, why do not to use `ng-options` - You just need to add new value to list of objects  and `ng-options` will do the job for you:

<kbd>[Simple Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmw8zstf/)</kbd>

```
$scope.items = [
    { value: "C", name: "Process C" },
    { value: "Q", name: "Process Q" }
];
 $timeout(function(){
    $scope.items.push({ value: "New", name: "Process New" });
 },3000);
```

and HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="theModel" ng-model="theModel" 
        ng-options="c.value as c.name for c in items">
    <option value=""> -- </option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Is possible to do this after a change on external model field ? Watch a field and then add the option ?

Comment: @MartinIrigaray Not at all. `compile` is called once right after we created the instance. I think this is a right answer for your question you posted. However if you want to create value after delay, why you don't want to use `ng-options`? You just need to add new value to list of objects and and `ng-options` will do the job for you: http://jsfiddle.net/21on92dk/

Answer (score 2):

Actually, what you have failed to understand is data binding. It means that when you have something in the $scope, you have to work with it. So your variable $scope.opcion must be an array as it is a select. The code needs to be something like:

```
/*
AngularJS Basic Directives

For More Examples AngularJS  

http://mehmetcanker.com

*/

var myApp = angular.module('example', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.opcion = [1];
}])

 //This directive doesn't individual scope so
 //Controller and Directive share same scope
 myApp.directive('myList', function() {
   return {
        restrict: 'EA', //E = element, A = attribute, C = class, M = comment
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
          // add options
          $scope.opcion.join(2);
        } //DOM manipulation
    }
  });
```

The important part is `$scope.opcion = [1]`  and `$scope.opcion.join(value)`